# magnifying glass displaying irrelevant content in UITextField

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uitextfield

I have developed an iOS app in Xamarin. I have few UITExtFields  in UIScrollview. when user touch on UITetField, I am setting contentOffSet of scrollview so it can be visible when keyboard appears.

```
this.txtUsername.ShouldBeginEditing += delegate {
            scrl.SetContentOffset (new CoreGraphics.CGPoint (0, this.txtUsername.ShouldBeginEditing.Frame.Location.Y - 50),true);
            return true;
        };
```

This works fine. But when I long press on textField, Magnifying glass is appearing and displaying irrelevant detail. -Its displaying detail which is behind the scroll view.

Major problem is- even If I push new viewcontroller, which is SignupView controller, Its displaying Previous screens image in Magnifying glass. Its not problem with only this app, I have similar problem in other app too - which is also developed using Xamarin

I have uploaded video of my app for better understanding of problem I am facing [here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/anvolh24xz1fqop/magnifying%20Glass%20error.mov?dl=0)

[image: Screenshot of what its displaying in magnifying glass]

[image: Screenshot of another app- what its displaying in magnifying glass]

Comment: Hi, Did you finally figure out what was causing this issue ? We're facing the same problem as of now.

Comment: Hi  @ShariqueAbdullah. Yes I solved it. It was problem in Appdelegate class file. for iPhone and iPad i had different storyboards and I was setting root view controller of windows with required storyboard...That was problem. I fixed it by assigning storyboard from plist file. --If you are adding anything on WINDOW from didFinishLaunch method, remove that. That will solve problem.

Comment: Hi, That's great. Thanks for the help :).

Comment: @ShariqueAbdullah Did that solve your problem ?

Comment: Kind of, we got to the root of the problem based on your replay. The fix we finally put in was increasing the UIWindow.WindowLevel property of the currently visible window to something greater than the normal level, whenever we make a switch from one storyboard to another.