# How to disable Long press gesture recogniser in UITextField and UISearchBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, long-press

I come across many post about disabling long press in UItextView, but that same process is not working for UITextField and UISearchBar.

Is there any way to disable Long press on UITextField and UISearchBar so I can avoid Magnifying glass on long press?

I have already checked "[Disable Magnifying Glass in UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866200/disable-magnifying-glass-in-uitextfield)" but  solution given there is not actually disabling magnifying glass. Its just not allowing cursory to Move between text. but still displaying Magnifying glass.

I want to disable Long Press - to avoid [Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40930220/magnifying-glass-displaying-irrelevant-content-in-uitextfield) which I am facing with magnifying glass. I want to disable it now. will enable it again when I will able to fix this.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866200/disable-magnifying-glass-in-uitextfield

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640781/disable-magnifying-glass-in-uitextview

Comment: @Venkat answer given in this thread is something which fails in apple approval process. Its using private api.

Comment: @iOS_devloper pls check the accepted answer in the above link. Thats not private api.

Comment: @Venkat, Thanks, It worked for UITextField. But I want to disable it for UISearchbar too. Any idea?

Comment: do the same thing for search bar too.

Comment: Already tried. Not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can try following for disabling only built in long press gesture

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in textView.gestureRecognizers) {
  if ([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]]){
    recognizer.enabled = NO;
  }
}
```

or

delegate method for all :-

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
return NO;
}
```

Comment: If I Will return  NO from shouldChangeCharactersInRange it will not allow me to edit in textfield.

Comment: If you need editing then disable long press gesture only by first method

Comment: Removing long press gesture is working for TextField but not for UISearchbar.

Answer (score 0):

This combination in a custom class is the only thing I've been able to get to work for me, and on the first long press it still sometimes makes the magnifying glass appear:

```
//swift 4.2
override func addGestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)
{

    if gestureRecognizer.isKind(of: UILongPressGestureRecognizer.self)
    {
        print(gestureRecognizer.name.unwrappedDebugString)
        gestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false
    }
    return super.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
}
override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool
{
    for recognizer in self.gestureRecognizers ?? []
    {
        if (recognizer is UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
        {
            recognizer.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
    return super.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

@Neeraj answer in Swift 4 :

```
class CustomTextView: UITextView {

   override func addGestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {

     if gestureRecognizer.isKind(of: UILongPressGestureRecognizer.self) {
              gestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false
     }
    return super.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
   }
}
```

Comment: In iOS 12, if the text field is the first responder, the magnifying glass will still appear and the disappear quickly after the long press is finished with this code, interrupting touchUpInside.

Answer (score -2):

One good and clean way to do this is you can create a custom class for the UITextField and in the custom class you can override the long-press gesture which is causing the magnification view appear. 
This custom class can be used in all places where we don't want to show the magnification view for test field. Just use below class in place of UITextField class

```
class CustomTextView: UITextView {

    override func addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if (gestureRecognizer.isKindOfClass(UILongPressGestureRecognizer)) {
            gestureRecognizer.enabled = false;
        }
        super.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
        return
    }
}
```